# Module parse failed: Identifier 'NextResponse' has already been declared (3:6) Middleware.ts(NextJs)

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Before writing the `middleware.ts` file in the root directory of my nextJS app, it was working perfectly, after adding the middleware file with the following code

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"

export const config = { 
  matcher: [
    "/bookings",
    "/directories",
    "/listingsFavs"
  ]
};
```

and going to one of the above routes, i get this error **Module parse failed: Identifier 'NextResponse' has already been declared (3:6)**
[image: Module parse failed: Identifier 'NextResponse' has already been declared (3:6)]

Comment: That's all you have in the middleware?

Comment: yes, https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7650 suggested an upgrade, however am aready on Next 13.4

Comment: Where is your authentication configuration (**[...nextauth]**) located? I was having this issue and had placed it wrongly since it recently changed: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization#route-handlers-app

Answer (score 2):

**upgrade your next version to "next": "13.4.7" this worked for me**

previously its:"next": "13.4.4"

Answer (score 1):

In my case upgrading to **13.4.5-canary.0** solved the problem.

Delete node modules and upgrade your Next.js to **13.4.5**, and yarn then they will seek suggestion from you and select **13.4.5-canary.0**.

Comment: deleting the node_modules folder, and upgrading to 13.4.5-canary.0 creates dependency conflicts even after removing package-lock.json,

Comment: Editing my `package.json` for the **next** module to `"next": "13.4.4-canary.5"` fixed my problem, this is probably a temporary fix, i dont know of a permanent one